# Monotone Class Theorem Application

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, monotone-class-theorem

I am trying to proof the following statement. Let $h$ be a bounded, $\mathbb{F}$-predictable process with $\tau$ a $\mathbb{H}$-stopping time, we then like to prove 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(h_{\tau}\vert\mathcal{F}_{t})=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}h_{u}dF_{u}\Big\vert\mathcal{F}_{t}\right) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{equation}
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $\tau$. I have proven this result for $h_{t}=\mathbb{1}_{]v,w]}(t)B_{v}$ where $B_{v}\in\mathcal{F}_{v}$. I would now like to apply the Monotone Class Theorem as defined at:http://planetmath.org/functionalmonotoneclasstheorem. 
This is where I get stuck. It seems logical to choose $\mathcal{H}$ the set of $\mathbb{F}$-predictable processes $h$ such that $(*)$ holds. But I am rather confused as to how to proceed. (And what should $\mathcal{K}$ be?)

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: How is $\mathbb{H}$ related to $\mathbb{F}$ is it a typo ?

Comment: @ Math Girl : you should switch $\mathcal{H}$ with $\mathcal{K}$ and define $\mathcal{H}$ as the space of all bounded predictable processes. Best regards

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply. It was not a typo, they are not necessarily related. I am still not sure as to how to proceed.. how does the special case with the indicator come into play?

Comment: @ Math Gril : Not related but though $\mathbb{F}$ is a filtration over the sample space $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{H}$ is a sigma-algebra over $\Omega$ right ?

Comment: Yes. Any clue on how to help me out with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's go but I will only outline the solution (using theroem 2 of planetmath.org) :

Take $\mathcal{K}$ as of processes of the form  $\sum_{i=1}^n C_i.1[({s_i},{t_i}]\times A_{s_i}]$ where $0\leq {s_i}<{t_i}$, $s_i$ are increasing and $A_{s_i}\in\mathcal{F}_{s_i}$ (those processes are bounded and predictable, and $\mathcal{K}$ is stable by multiplication).

Now take $\mathcal{H}$ as the set of processes that are bounded and predictable and which verify (*). So we have $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ includes constants.

I'll let you check by use on dominated convergence (or monotone convergence) (which both work well even when conditioning with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$), that the condition in the bullet point of theorem 2 on $\mathcal{H}$ is satisfied.

This allows you to conclude that $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded predictable processes generated by the set of function $\mathcal{K}$, let's call it $\sigma(\mathcal{K})^b$, this in turn contains (prove it) all bounded predictable processes and so we are done because this is what we wanted from the beginning.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you so much! It is definitely becoming more clear now.

Comment: @ Math Girl : Hope it helps. In any case, MCT is always tricky because its logic works "backwards" in some sense. It's natural to define $\mathcal{K}$, and $\mathcal{H}$ as you did but MCT usually works the other way around. Best regards

Comment: Hi, I have one more question if you dont mind helping me out one more time. We have now used theorem 2 of planetmath.org which is techniquely only defined by function not stochastic processes. So is the above proof even correct?

Comment: @Math Girl : You can view stochastic processes as random variable in the functional space of càdlàg trajectories endowed with sufficiently good topology (Skorokhod topology is a classiscal choice in this regard). As I said I'm only giving you hints and let you work out the details. Best regards